# Can you loop over a panda df and array at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different sets of data being passed to a method. One is a panda dataframe and the other is an array. The dataframe has one column that I want to map to an array. Something like this

```
data = {'index':[2, 5, 1, 3],
        'file':["file1", "file2", "file3","file4" ]}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

labels = ["rope", "dope", "goat", "badger"]

for x,y in zip(df, labels):
        print(x[0])
        print(y)
```

The output I would like would look like this:

file1,dope
file2,dope
file3, goat

is there a straight forward way to do this or do i need to loop over both arrays and build a new one?

Comment: Do you want the output to be a list of tuples that contains something like: `[('file1', 'rope'), ('file2', 'dope'), ('file3', 'goat'), ('file4', 'badger')]`

Answer (score 4):

`more-itertools` has a method called [`interleave`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.interleave) that does this for you.

But if you don’t want to use the package then just use the recipe (it uses `zip` and `itertools.chain`):

```
print(*itertools.chain(*zip(data['fields'], labels)), sep=', ')
```

Results:

```
file1, rope, file2, dope, file3, goat, file4, badger
```

Comment: what does the * mean here in print?

Comment: To unpack the iterable as multiple arguments

Comment: the more i learn about itertools the more impressed I am, such a handy library.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I solved it right after asking. I was being dumber than usual.

```
data = {'index':[2, 5, 1, 3],
        'file':["file1", "file2", "file3","file4" ]}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

files = df["file"]
print(files)
labels = ["rope", "dope", "goat", "badger"]

for x,y in zip(files, labels):
        print(x)
        print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `list` and `zip` together to get the output.

```
data = {'index':[2, 5, 1, 3],
        'file':["file1", "file2", "file3","file4" ]}
labels = ["rope", "dope", "goat", "badger"]
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

output = list(zip(df['file'], labels))
```

Output will be:

```
[('file1', 'rope'), ('file2', 'dope'), ('file3', 'goat'), ('file4', 'badger')]
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

you want to sort by index then create a new array?

```
import itertools
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
new_arr = list(zip(df['file'],labels))
print(list(itertools.chain(*new_arr)))
out: 
['file3', 'rope', 'file1', 'dope', 'file4', 'goat', 'file2', 'badger']
```